# ORDER BY before GROUP BY for leaderboard

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table with all players results:

```
  id  |result| user_id
------------------------
  1   | 130  | 5C382072
  2   | 145  | 5C382072
  3   | 130  | 8QHDTz7w
  4   | 166  | 6155B6D0
  5   | 100  | DFSA3444
```

Smaller result is better. I need to make query for leaderboard.
Each player must appear once in leaderboard with his best result. If 2 players have equal results, the one with smaller id should appear first.
So I'm expecting this output:

```
  id  |result| user_id
------------------------
  5   | 100  | DFSA3444
  1   | 130  | 5C382072
  3   | 130  | 8QHDTz7w
  4   | 166  | 6155B6D0
```

I can't get desired result, cause grouping by `user_id` goes before ordering it by `result, id`.

My code:

```
SELECT id, MIN(result), user_id
FROM results
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY result, id
```

It output something close to desired result, but `id` field is not connected to row with smallest user result, it can be any `id` from group with the same `user_id`. Because of that   ordering by `id` not work at all.

**EDIT:**

What I didn't mention before is that I need to handle situations when user have identical results.

I came up with two solutions that I don't like. :)

1) A bit slow and ugly:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM results WHERE results_status=1) t1 
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT * FROM results WHERE results_status=1) t2 
  ON (t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND (t1.result > t2.result OR (t1.result = t2.result AND t1.id > t2.id)))
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY result, id
```

2) Ten times slower but more clear:

```
SELECT *
FROM results t1
WHERE id = (
  SELECT id 
  FROM results 
  WHERE user_id = t1.user_id AND results_status=1 
  ORDER BY result, id 
  LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY result, id
```

I'm stuck. :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem by adding your code. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you close. Avoid MySQL's lenient (errant) GROUP BY syntax, which lets you form a GROUP BY clause without naming unaggregated columns from the SELECT list. Use standard SQL's GROUP BY syntax instead.

```
select t.user_id, m.min_result, min(t.id) id
from results t
inner join (select user_id, min(result) min_result
            from results
            group by user_id) m
        on t.user_id = m.user_id
       and t.result = m.min_result
group by t.user_id, m.min_result
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand, really. :) But, this solution is faster than my. Easy to change query conditions. For example, you can show only last week result. Easy to add additional fields from row by JOIN ON id. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I think you need a subquery:

```
SELECT a.id, a.result, a.user_id FROM results a 
WHERE a.user_id, a.result IN (SELECT b.user_id, MIN(b.result) FROM results b 
    GROUP BY b.user_id)
ORDER BY a.user_id
```

This will return an undefined `id` if the same user had the same score more than once, but will order the users correctly and will match `id` to the correct `user_id`.

Comment: No, it's not. `id` will be not connected to result row. So, for second output row in my example it could be 1 or 2. Because `id` is not aggregated output result will be indeterminate. `The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause.` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: Thank you for your editing. Undefined id is the main problem.